# 503 error AWS ELB after DNS migration

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I recently migrated my wordpress on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
I also migrated my DNS zone from OVH to AWS route 53.

Now when I go to my website I get 503 error (even if I push a fresh wordpress installation on Elastic Beanstalk).
When I ping my DNS I get the right IP address.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer, problem was caused by HTTPS listener.

I have to listen on 443 port and redirect on 80 port of the instance.
I redirected on 443 port of the instance, but wordpress listen on 80.

It's ok now, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

At the first try with your EC2 IP address directly, if you can see your Wordpress go to next part and put it behind the ELB.

**Make sure about the following things:**

1-Open port 80 on the security group for EC2.

2-Map the right port for listeners between your EC2 and ELB.

3-Set the proper health check for EC2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually when I install a fresh wordpress, it work with canonical address of elastic beanstalk (***.elasticbeanstalk.com) but not with my DNS. And on route 53, I created an alias on elastic beanstalk directly (not on the load balancer).

Comment: Which records did you add in your zone?

Comment: Check this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html

Comment: I already followed this documentation, I've add an ALIAS (IPV4) with my EB environment as target